# Land Surveyor Coordinates

Tags: coordinates, wgs84

I've received these coordinates from a land surveyor and no matter which converter I try or where I insert these coordinates.

I really can't find them in Google Earth or any other map.

If anyone can please assist;

[image]

Comment: But you probably know approximately where it should be? That would help a lot.

Comment: Correct, it's near Bela-Bela, South-Africa. But I need to locate and point the exact points

Comment: Here WG 21 was looked after: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88589/what-does-coordinate-system-wg-21-mean
maybe it helps to find your WG 29

Comment: Going to epsg.io (https://epsg.io/) and searching for Lo29 gives you two most likely candidates: EPSG 2053 and EPSG 22289. First coordinate in your table is X and second Y. You have to add constant 2,700.000 to Y. See https://epsg.io/map#srs=2053&x=72059&y=2754243.758028&z=9&layer=streets

Comment: After a quick look, I think @TomazicM is right here. I did try and put the coordinates into QGIS but didn't have a base map to check them.

Comment: Thank you for your help @TomazicM, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Just so the answer is in here and not in the comments, I'm adding based on @TomazicM answer above

> Going to epsg.io (epsg.io) and searching for Lo29 gives you two most likely candidates: EPSG 2053 and EPSG 22289. First coordinate in your table is X and second Y. You have to add constant 2,700.000 to Y. See https://epsg.io/map#srs=2053&x=72058.999544&y=2754243.758563&z=9&layer=streets

Comment: @TomazicM Are you sure the first coordinate is X and the second is Y? The left column header is Y and the right column header is X. Are the headers wrong?

Comment: @CSK Yes, I'm sure. Yust click one the epsg.io link in the above answer any you'll see Bela-Bela, as it was clearified as destination in comments to the question.