# Converting projected coordinates for Botswana

Tags: coordinates

I live in Botswana.
How can I convert the coordinates they gave me on a lease?
I think it is very old system they use. Google Maps do not accept the coordinates. and ?earthplane? web age is only for USA.

On the lease is:

```
A=Y59665 X2493871
B=Y59460 X2493980
C=Y59701 X2494360
D=Y59819 X2494297
```

How do I convert the X & Y to degrees, minutes and seconds?

I have been searching in every Google site for a converter for these types of coordinates.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please do not use ALL CAPS in your posts here.

Comment: Sorry my caps lock was on from searching the X and Y coordinates... I am so confused by this things

Comment: There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise your question at any time.

Comment: Ok, must I change my question? I just want to ask someone who can help me to convert this Y59665 coordinate to a coordinate that google maps can understand. Because google maps do not read this type of coordinates?? what can I do??

Comment: If you want someone to read your question (and answer it), then yes you should [edit] the question. If folks have a choice between reading an all-caps post and moving on to a new question, it's not going to be a close call.

Comment: You have two different accounts, which makes it difficult to edit your own post. Please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to correct this.  The folks from whom you have leased are far more likely to be able to tell you the coordinate system they used than we are.

Comment: But you probably know approximately where in Botswana this should be? Is this somwhere in between Thabala and Motshegaletau?

Answer (score 1):

Correct CRS for these coordinates is EPSG:22287 (Cape / Lo27). Conversion from projected coordinates to EPSG:4326 (WGS 84) can be done at epsg.io: https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=22287&t_srs=4326&x=58958.4440060&y=2491707.7922860

When converting, you have to swap X and Y. For example, for first coordinate `A=Y59665 X2493871`, when converting, it should be:

```
X = 59665
Y = 2493871
```

and converted coordinates are:

```
lon = 26°25'35.696" (26.4265822°)
lat = -22°31'28.591" (-22.5246087°)
```

How I found the correct CRS was by luck. Shortly ago I was helping somebody finding the right CRS in South Africa ([Land Surveyor Coordinates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329957/land-surveyor-coordinates)). Since Botswana lies above SA and coordinates seemed similar, I searched at epsg.io first for Lo29, then Lo28 and finally Lo27, which was the right one. Pure (informed) quessing.

Comment: You are correct yes it is about 120km from Motshegaletau. I founded it online, the coordinates. I know that district uses -22° and just put that in front of the Y coordinates and the X they just left out the . after 24. The owners was given this lands and do not know where the land are. Some cannot read and write.

Answer (score 0):

Botswana's grid coordinates is divided into bands of 2° and given as Lo21, Lo23 up to Lo27. Therefore to convert your coordinates the band that they belong to should be known.